# Grails Acegi : Redirection on a ajax method and not on the webpage. Why?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I use Acegi with grails but I have a problem with a redirection.

I define in UrlMapping this :

```
"/" { 
  controller = "mycontroller"
  action = "myaction"
}
```

In mycontroller :

```
myaction = {
    if (authenticateService.isLoggedIn(){ "/mycontext/public" }
    else {
       // pseudo code
       if (role = ROLE_1) {
           redirect "/mycontext/myactionforNormalUser"
       }
       else if (role = ROLE_ADMIN) {
           redirect "/mycontext/myactionforROLEADMIN"
       }
    }
}
```

IfI go to my app without login, I'm redirected to the public page, so it's right.
But on login on admin, I'm redirected to the auth/deniedAjax (of acegi) and not on my page.
And if I login as a normal user, I'm redirect on a ajax method define in my gsp.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might not have much luck getting support on an old, out dated, unsupported plugin.  You should really look into upgrading to the spring-security-core plugin: http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/index.html

Comment: +1 for upgrading to spring security

Comment: I upgrade now. I add my feedback later. Thanks

Comment: I upgraded to SpringSecurity and it's working fine now. Thanks

Comment: But now, after some changes it is not working. After my login, users are redirected to an ajax method. But the default url is "/". I don't understand!

Comment: When I try with firefox, he open a popup to save the json file. If I click on cancel and I click on login again. It's works fine. So why I have this redirection to my ajax method?

Comment: It seems that the reason is that a script with a call to the ajax has been on the top of my gsp file. I put it on the en of the gsp file and it's working.

Comment: @JonathanLebrun please post the upgrade as answer and accept it, so others will not spend time seeing the closed topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded and working fine now with spring security